# Is Java 7 OSX printing broken?

Tags: macos, printing, java-7

I have several existing java applications that print documents. Since the Java 7 upgrade, printing on OSX seems to be broken. Everything works fine on Windows Java 6 and Java 7. Printing is also working on OSX Java 6, but on OSX Java 7 it is not.

I also reported it to Oracle, but have heard nothing back.

To keep it simple I downloaded the [Oracle printing example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/examples/HelloWorldPrinter.java) and tested with that.

[image: OSX Java 6]

[image: OSX Java 7]

```
/* Now we perform our rendering */
g.drawString ("Hello world!", 100, 100);

String fontName = "Monospaced";

g2d.setFont (new Font (fontName, Font.PLAIN, 8));
g2d.drawString ("Hello world - 8 point", 100, 130);

g.setFont (new Font (fontName, Font.PLAIN, 18));
g.drawString ("Hello world - 18 point", 100, 160);

g.setFont (new Font (fontName, Font.PLAIN, 30));
g.drawString ("Hello world - 30 point", 100, 190);
```

Comment: Have you found any resolution?

Comment: I received an email from Oracle on 24 February saying 'We have determined that this report is a new bug and entered the bug into our internal bug tracking system under Bug Id: 9000082.'. It contained a link to http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=9000082. But it appears to have been closed.

Comment: That's brutal. I know a lot of people are struggling through this issue. Well pretty much anyone use Java 7 on the Mac. I can't understand why it's been left to linger for so long... Thanks for the update, it's appreciated.

Comment: I've just noticed that Oracle claims to have fixed it in 7u40 http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7183516